# Cannot Email By GoDaddy Office365 in Django ([Errno 101] Network is unreachable)

Tags: python, django, outlook, smtp, office365

I have deployed my Django project on GoDaddy hosting. I have a problem while emailing by SMTP server using the provided Office365 mail on GoDaddy. The config which I set for emailing is code below.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.office365.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'no-reply@domain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
```

But while sending an email by the send function from an instance of Django EmailMessage class, error “[Errno 101] Network is unreachable” is being returned (I have also tried different ports none of them has solved the problem yet). I thank anyone to guide me with the solution.
Thanks,